# Software to convert mp4 to mp4 for iPhone

Tags: macos, video, iphone, conversion, mp4

I've a huge mp4 video. What software is good to use to convert that file to an iPhone optimized video?

Preferably for Mac OS X and free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also **iTunes**. Select the video and under the `Advanced` menu item there is an option `Convert to iPod or iPhone version`.

Answer (score 8):

For easy-to-use, I'd recommend HandBrake (http://handbrake.fr/)

For powerful, you really can't beat ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

As parker stated, FFmpeg is the de facto standard for free video and audio conversion. If are afraid of the command line, VLC has a transcoding feature as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has the command line `afconvert` tool for simple needs.  We used 'Amadeus Pro' for our last project.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take at look at Miro or Videora. Miro uses ffmpeg if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) is simple to use and free.

It has iPhone presets.